# Facing issues with adding sharedPreferences and the sharedPrefrencesEditor to Koin module

Tags: dependency-injection, koin

I recently got to know about Koin. 
I was trying to migrate my current project from Dagger to Koin.
In doing so, I faced an issue with injecting **sharedPreferences and sharedPreferences editor** in the activities.

Following is the code I used in ***Dagger*** to inject sharedPreferences and sharedPreferences editor ->

```
    @Provides
    @AppScope
    fun getSharedPreferences(context: Context): SharedPreferences =
            context.getSharedPreferences("default", Context.MODE_PRIVATE)

    @SuppressLint("CommitPrefEdits")
    @Provides
    @AppScope
    fun getSharedPrefrencesEditor(context: Context): SharedPreferences.Editor =
            getSharedPreferences(context).edit()
```

I tried to convert the above mentioned code to ***Koin*** like this ->

```
val appModule = module {

    val ctx by lazy{ androidApplication() }

    single {
        ctx.getSharedPreferences("default", Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
    }

    single {
        getSharedPreferences(ctx).edit()
    }
}
```

I also tried to implement it this way ->

```
val appModule = module {

        single {
            androidApplication().getSharedPreferences("default", Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
        }

        single {
            getSharedPreferences(androidApplication()).edit()
        }
    }
```

Now I inject the dependencies in my activity like this ->

```
val sharedPreferences: SharedPreferences by inject()

val sharedPreferencesEditor: SharedPreferences.Editor by inject()
```

But as soon as I launch my app and try to use them, I am not able to read or write anything to the preferences.

I am a bit confused as to what is wrong with the code. 
Kindly help me figure this out.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I figured out a way to handle this.
Hope this helps someone looking for the same issue.

Here is the solution to the problem:

The koin module definition will be like this ->

```
 val appModule = module {

    single{
        getSharedPrefs(androidApplication())
    }

    single<SharedPreferences.Editor> {
        getSharedPrefs(androidApplication()).edit()
    }
 }

fun getSharedPrefs(androidApplication: Application): SharedPreferences{
    return  androidApplication.getSharedPreferences("default",  android.content.Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
}
```

Just to be clear that the above code is in the file **modules.kt**

Now you can easily inject the created instances like ->

```
private val sharedPreferences: SharedPreferences by inject()

private val sharedPreferencesEditor: SharedPreferences.Editor by inject()
```

Make sure the above instances are **val** instead of **var** otherwise the inject() method will not work as this is lazy injection.

Comment: Is hardcoding the word "default" actually gives the default SharedPreference?

Comment: i am getting error of  `Caused by: org.koin.core.error.NoBeanDefFoundException: No definition found for 'android.content.SharedPreferences' has been found. Check your module definitions`

Comment: @Shvet have you found solution for this?

Comment: @Noorul Don't remember much now, at that time i was also learning koin implementation and it been 2 years. i have to go and find old code.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72688110/no-bean-definition-found-exception

Comment: its been 21 hours. still I didn't get answer.

Comment: I think it is better to create a function to get the editor of the SharedPreferences like this :  `fun getSharedPrefsEditor(sharedPreferences: SharedPreferences):SharedPreferences.Editor = sharedPreferences.edit()` 
 and get it like this:     `single { getSharedPrefsEditor(get()) }`
your code create two SharedPreferences object and I think it is wrong.