# No Bean Definition Found exception

Tags: android, kotlin, koin

```
2022-06-20 18:59:22.201 20149-20149/com.xx.xxxx E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.xx.xxxx, PID: 20149
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:681)
 Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:791)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:681) 
 Caused by: org.koin.core.error.NoBeanDefFoundException: |- No definition found for class:'com.xx.xxxx.di.PreferencesManager'. Check your definitions!
    at org.koin.core.scope.Scope.throwDefinitionNotFound(Scope.kt:304)
    at org.koin.core.scope.Scope.resolveValue(Scope.kt:274)
    at org.koin.core.scope.Scope.resolveInstance(Scope.kt:241)
    at org.koin.core.scope.Scope.get(Scope.kt:204)
    at com.xx.xxxx.SplashActivity$special$$inlined$inject$default$1.invoke(ComponentCallbackExt.kt:61)
    at kotlin.SynchronizedLazyImpl.getValue(LazyJVM.kt:74)
    at com.xx.xxxx.SplashActivity.getMyPref(SplashActivity.kt:16)
    at com.xx.xxxx.SplashActivity.callNextScreen(SplashActivity.kt:28)
    at com.xx.xxxx.SplashActivity.onCreate$lambda-0(SplashActivity.kt:24)
    at com.xx.xxxx.SplashActivity.$r8$lambda$ZKKoKfwsv3qwgbmTc6lA0Ow_bOM(SplashActivity.kt)
    at com.xx.xxxx.SplashActivity$$ExternalSyntheticLambda0.run(D8$$SyntheticClass)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:179)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5730)
```

I am facing some issue on Koin DI.

```
import android.app.Application
import org.koin.android.ext.koin.androidContext
import org.koin.core.context.loadKoinModules
import org.koin.core.context.startKoin

//import org.koin.core.context.GlobalContext.startKoin
//import org.koin.android.ext.android.startKoin
class BaseApplication : Application() {

companion object {
    lateinit var ins: BaseApplication
}

override fun onCreate() {
    super.onCreate()
    ins = this
    startKoin {
        androidContext(this@BaseApplication)
     //            modules(listOf(appModule, repoModule, viewModelModule))
        val modules = listOf(
            appModule
        )
        loadKoinModules(modules)
    }
    }
    }
```

My AppModuleClassBelow

```
  val appModule = module {
 
     single { provideAppPreference(androidApplication()) }

  }
  private fun provideAppPreference(application: Application): PreferencesManager {
  val myPref = application.applicationContext.getSharedPreferences(
    "Patient",
    Context.MODE_PRIVATE
  )
   return PreferencesManager(myPref)
 }
```

My PreferenceManagerClass is below

```
class PreferencesManager(private val myPref: SharedPreferences) {


companion object {
    var KEY_AUTH_TOKEN = "auth_token"
    var KEY_FCM_TOKEN = "fcm_token"
    var KEY_USER_MODEL = "user_model"
}

fun isLogin(): Boolean {
    return getUserModel()?.firstname?.isNotEmpty() == true
}

fun getMobileNumber(): String {
    return getUserModel()?.phone ?: ""
}

fun getEmail(): String {
    return getUserModel()?.email ?: ""
}

fun getUserName(): String {
    return getUserModel()?.firstname ?: ""
}

fun getUserModel(): UserModel? {
    return Gson().fromJson(getStringValue(KEY_USER_MODEL), UserModel::class.java)
}

fun setUserModel(userModel: UserModel?) {
    val str = Gson().toJson(userModel, UserModel::class.java)
    setStringValue(KEY_USER_MODEL, str)
}

fun getNameForPayment(): String {
    val s = getUserName()
    return if (s.isEmpty()) {
        getStr(R.string.app_name)
    } else {
        s
    }
}

fun getEmailForPayment(): String {
    val s = getEmail()
    return if (s.isEmpty()) {
        "info@labsdone.com"
    } else {
        s
    }
}

fun getMobileForPayment(): String {
    val s = getMobileNumber()
    return if (s.isEmpty() || s.length < 10) {
        "9876543210"
    } else {
        s
    }
}

fun resetCartList() {
    val currentUserId = getStringValue("UserId")
    myPref.edit().putString("cart_list$currentUserId", "").commit()
}

fun generateFCMToken() {
    //   myPref.saveFCM("Test fcmToken");
    /*FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().token
        .addOnCompleteListener { task: Task<String?> ->
            if (!task.isSuccessful) {
                setStringValue(PREF_KEY_FCM_TOKEN,"Fetching FCM registration token failed " + task.exception)
                Log.w(ContentValues.TAG,"Fetching FCM registration token failed",task.exception)
                return@addOnCompleteListener
            }

            // Get new FCM registration token
            val fcmToken = task.result
            if (fcmToken != null) {
                if (fcmToken.isNotEmpty()) {
                    setStringValue(PREF_KEY_FCM_TOKEN,fcmToken)
                } else {
                    setStringValue(PREF_KEY_FCM_TOKEN,"GetInstanceId Failed")
                }
            }
        }*/
}

fun getLastReservationId(): String {
    return getStringValue("reservationId")
}

fun setLastReservationId(token: String?) {
    setStringValue("reservationId", token)
}

fun getLastStationId(): String {
    return getStringValue("StationId")
}

fun setLastStationId(token: String?) {
    setStringValue("StationId", token)
}

fun getAccessToken(): String {
    return getStringValue(KEY_AUTH_TOKEN)
}

fun setAccessToken(token: String?) {
    setStringValue(KEY_AUTH_TOKEN, token)
}

fun setStringValue(keyName: String?, value: String?) {
    myPref.edit().putString(keyName, value).apply()
}

fun getStringValue(keyName: String?): String {
    return AppValidator.toStr(myPref.getString(keyName, ""))
}

fun setBooleanValue(keyName: String?, value: Boolean) {
    myPref.edit().putBoolean(keyName, value).apply()
}

fun getBooleanValue(keyName: String?): Boolean {
    return myPref.getBoolean(keyName, false)
}

fun setIntValue(keyName: String?, value: Int) {
    myPref.edit().putInt(keyName, value).apply()
}

fun getIntValue(keyName: String?): Int {
    return myPref.getInt(keyName, 0)
}

fun remove(key: String?) {
    myPref.edit().remove(key).apply()
}

fun clear(): Boolean {
    return myPref.edit().clear().commit()
}

fun resetAllPref() {
    clear()
}


}
```

I am using this DI for store some information for my app. I have inject this in my Activity. like below.

```
   private val myPref: PreferencesManager by inject()
```

But when I try to access this, I am getting above mentioned error and app crashes.

Yours help really appreciated.

**EDIT**

I tried with not lazy type injection. facing the same Error.

```
 private val myPref: PreferencesManager = get ()
```

**EDIT**

When I debug after injection on Splashactivity I am getting following response, response is attached as image

[image: image here]

> Lazy value not initialised yet error coming.

Did I make any mistake on this? after this line, app crashes with above error.

> org.koin.core.error.NoBeanDefFoundException

**EDIT**

instead of single, if I used Scope component, like below,

```
val activityModule = module {
scope<SplashActivity> {
    scoped<PreferencesManager> {
        provideAppPreference(androidApplication())
    }
}

}

private fun provideAppPreference(application: Application): PreferencesManager {
 val myPref = application.applicationContext.getSharedPreferences(
    "default",
    Context.MODE_PRIVATE
)
  return PreferencesManager(myPref)
}
```

and the injection as follows,

```
class SplashActivity : AppCompatActivity(),AndroidScopeComponent{

override val scope: Scope by activityScope()
private val myPref:PreferencesManager by inject<PreferencesManager>()

private lateinit var binding: ActivitySplashBinding

//    private val userViewModel:UsersViewModel by viewModel()
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    binding = ActivitySplashBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
    setContentView(binding.root)
    changeStatusBarColor(getColorCompat(R.color.white), true)
 //        makeSendOtpReq()
    Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).postDelayed({
        callNextScreen()
    }, 5000)

}
private fun callNextScreen() {
    if(!myPref.isLogin()){
        startActivity(Intent(this, AuthActivity::class.java))
    }else{
        startActivity(Intent(this, MainActivity::class.java))
    }

   /* startActivity(Intent(this, MainActivity::class.java))
    finish()
  */
   }
  }
```

this is working fine. it is not working on single only. I don't know why. Anybody know means, provide the feedback.

Helps will be appreciated.

Comment: Hello take look to this solution :
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51195471/koin-android-org-koin-error-nobeandeffoundexception

Comment: I tried this. but not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've got it to work first try, here's the code that I have used:

```kotlin
// StackOverflow72688110App.kt
package com.trifork.stackoverflow72688110

import android.app.Application
import android.content.Context
import android.content.SharedPreferences
import android.util.Log
import org.koin.android.ext.koin.androidContext
import org.koin.android.ext.koin.androidLogger
import org.koin.core.context.loadKoinModules
import org.koin.core.context.startKoin
import org.koin.dsl.module

val appModule = module {
    single {
        val sharedPreferences = sharedPreferences("Patient", get())
        PreferenceManager(sharedPreferences)
    }
}


class PreferenceManager(private val sharedPreferences: SharedPreferences) {
    fun printSomething() {
        Log.d("PreferenceManager", "Hi from injected PreferenceManager")
        Log.d("PreferenceManager", sharedPreferences.all.toString())
    }
}

class StackOverflow72688110App : Application() {

    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()
        val app = this
        startKoin {
            androidContext(app)
            androidLogger()
            loadKoinModules(appModule)
        }
    }
}


private fun sharedPreferences(prefsName: String, context: Context): SharedPreferences =
    context.getSharedPreferences(prefsName, Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
```

```kotlin
// MainActivity.kt
package com.trifork.stackoverflow72688110

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import org.koin.android.ext.android.inject

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private val preferenceManager by inject<PreferenceManager>()
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        preferenceManager.printSomething()
    }
}
```

The output that this code yields:

[image: logging output]

---

#### Now to why yours doesn't work?

1. Make sure you've added `android:name=".StackOverflow72688110App"` to your `<application>` in the `AndroidManifest.xml` file. This ensures that your `onCreate` method will be called and hence the `startKoin` as well.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <application
        android:name=".StackOverflow72688110App"
        ...>
...
    </application>

</manifest>
```

2. From your activity make sure your import for inject is `import org.koin.android.ext.android.inject`
3. Make sure that the generic that you pass into the inject is the **correct class of PreferenceManager**. Note that exists a class in `android.preference.PreferenceManager` that is not the one you're interested in. So make sure you're importing the right package name for your `PreferenceManager`

Answer (score 0):

replace

```
import org.koin.standalone.StandAloneContext.startKoin
```

To

```
import org.koin.android.ext.android.startKoin
```

Comment: import org.koin.android.ext.android.startKoin, here startKoin is unresolve symbol

Comment: the comment Aymen Ben Salah is saying the same.